# combine GET and POST services to single one?

Tags: java, rest

I have two controllers I wrote using JERSEY api. I am able to run both services just fine, but I would like to join the two of them under the same ImageApi controller eliminating the SubmitFileController. Is it possible to have @Get method and @POST in the same controller? How will it handle the different paths?

currently its: `server/image/getPictureById` and `server/submitFile` (using post)

code:

```
@Path("/image")
public class ImageApi extends ServiceAPI{   
    @Path("/getPictureById/{imageId}")
    @GET
    @Produces("image/png")
    public Response getPictureById(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId){}
```

this image service gets the contextfrom Service API:

```
public class ServiceAPI {
    @Context 
    private ServletContext context;
    public ServletContext getContext() {return context;}
    public void setContext(ServletContext context) {this.context = context;}
}
```

and

```
@Path("/submitFile")
public class SubmitFileController {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {}
```

Comment: *combine GET and POST services to single one?* But why ?

Comment: "_Is it possible to have Get method and POST in the same controller?_" Yes. "_How will it handle the different paths?_" The paths can be the exact same and depending on if the user sends a GET or POST it will go to the correct method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to have @Get method and @POST in the same controller?

Yes

How will it handle the different paths?

If you have `@Path("/image/getPictureById/")` above the GET method, then `/image/getPictureById/` gets appended to the @Path annotation of the controller, if the annotation exists. So the path would become `server/submitFile/image/getPictureById/` unless you moved the @Path annotation of the controller to the POST method instead (in which case your http API will stay the same).

Note: You can process GET and POST requests at the exact same path, if you wanted to (doesn't seem to apply here).

```
public class Controller {
    @Path("/submitFile")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {}

    @Path("/image/getPictureById/{imageId}")
    @GET
    @Produces("image/png")
    public Response getPictureById(@PathParam("imageId") String imageId){}
```

Comment: So how to keep both urls like server/submitFile/   # and server/image/getPictureById   ?    Can you add sample code?

Comment: Don't put @Path above the class, just the methods. (I will say it looks a little funny to have such different paths existing in the same class, and am only showing how it's possible, but not necessarily "good".)